# HTML radio checked depends on where click came from

Tags: html, radio-button

I have one 'contact form' and two 'contact us' buttons.
My contact form includes two radio buttons. I want to make the first radio checked if visitor gets form through 'contact us' 1 and second radio checked if visitor gets my form from 'contact us' 2.
Here is an example image:

[image]

Comment: what attempt have you made at trying to do this? please show some code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't attempt anything yet
but one more again i will explain

I have html page contain contact form in the end of it 
and in the header there are two buttons 
1st contact from usa 
2nd contact from out side usa

I want to add some codes or script if visitor click 1st button the radio will be checked as usa and if he will click 2nd button radio will be checked out site usa as the above image
 BEST REGARDS